# In Haskell (ghc) Control.Exception, the difference between try and catch

Tags: exception, haskell, asynchronous, try-catch, ghc

all!
I'm a bit confused.

Is there inconsistency between document and code in library Control.Exception?

The document say that the function 'catch' use the function 'mask' on a handler function
but a function try doesn't use a function mask.

But the code say that the function 'try' use the function 'catch'.

I think that
if the function 'catch' use the function 'mask'
and the function 'try' use the function 'catch',
then the function 'try' use the function 'mask'.

---

In Control.Exception of ghc base-package, the document say

"There's an implied mask around every exception handler in a call to one of the catch family of functions. This is because that is what you want most of the time - it eliminates a common race condition in starting an exception handler, because there may be no exception handler on the stack to handle another exception if one arrives immediately. If asynchronous exceptions are masked on entering the handler, though, we have time to install a new exception handler before being interrupted. If this weren't the default, one would have to write something like

```
  mask $ \restore ->
       catch (restore (...))
             (\e -> handler)
```

If you need to unblock asynchronous exceptions again in the exception handler, restore can be used there too.

Note that try and friends do not have a similar default, because there is no exception handler in this case. Don't use try for recovering from an asynchronous exception. ".

But, the code say

"try a = catch (a >>= \ v -> return (Right v)) (\e -> return (Left e))"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this comment means is that if you use `try` like this:

```
e <- try act
case e of
    Left e  -> handleError e
    Right r -> doSomething r
```

there won't be a mask around the term `handleError e`, unlike in the case of `catch act handleError`.